# Retrieve data for Search Results from Parse.com

Tags: uitableview, uisearchbar, parse-platform

excuse me , I'm implementing a search bar through a tutorial video on youtube and specific use Parse.com

I would like to know how I can retrieve data from another parse and embed it in the search based on the code I have now ? Ie in addition to name the time the user would also like the photo ... I can not enter another search string ... Sorry for the banality of the question ... but they are totally stops ..

```
- (Void) { retrieveFromParse
    PFQuery retrievePets * = [ PFQuery queryWithClassName : FF_USER_CLASS ] ;
    [ retrievePets whereKeyExists : FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME ] ;
    
    
    [ retrievePets findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock : ^ ( NSArray * objects , NSError * error ) {
        if ( error) {
            NSLog ( @ "% @ " , objects) ;
            totalStrings = [ [ NSMutableArray alloc ] init ] ;
            for ( PFObject * object in objects) {
                NSString * animal = [object objectForKey : FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME ] ;

                [ totalStrings addObject : animal] ;
            }
            
        }
        [ self.FFTableViewFindUser reloadData ] ;
    } ] ;
}
```

Comment: Even more ideas are well accepted ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically how you are filtering is wrong.. you should try to store the objects itself rather than strings only. When retrieving.. directly add object to the array.

```
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        [allObjects addObject:object];
        //NSString *animal = [object objectForKey:FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME];

    }
```

now in CellForRow.. you can just get the image directly for the filtered one

```
   PFObject *object = [filteredObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *str = [object objectForKey:FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME];

  cell.FFLabelCell_NomeCognome.text = str;
    cell.FFIMGCell_FotoProfilo.file = [object objectForKey:FF_USER_FOTOPROFILO];
    [cell.FFIMGCell_FotoProfilo loadInBackground];
```